# "Unable to connect to target server" error occurred while trying to publish sql server project from visual studio 2013

Tags: database, visual-studio-2013, publish

I had an SQL server 2012 database project created in my VS2013. When I try to publish it to SQL Server 2014, it throws "Unable to connect to target server".

I verified the connection setting and the test connection is working fine, it fails only during publish action.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBlQc.png)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a SQL Database project created using Visual Studio 2013, which you are trying to deploy in SQL Server 2014 instance, you may be receiving an error stating that the data tools are “Unable to connect to target server”:

Most possible reason for this error is You haven't updated/installed **"SQL Server Data tools For SQL Server 2014".**

Open Visual studio 2013

Select "Tools" -> "Extensions and Updates.." menu.

Select “Updates” -> “Product Updates”

select the “Microsoft SQL Server Update for database tooling” and click the “Update” button.

complete the installation and open your database project in VS2013 and "publish" agian.  **This time it should work as expected**.